# Pushing to a Git repo that started as public but is now private

Tags: git

I setup a public repo on GitHub. I pushed my code a couple times and have now made that same repo private. And when I try and push I can't. I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

How can I push to my newly private repo? No clue

EDIT: I'm not simply pushing to a private repo. I'm pushing to a repo that CHANGED from public to private. Here are the steps I've attempted and the response I'm getting:
    me:
    git init

```
response:
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /opt/XXXX/.git/

me:
git remote add origin https://github.com/all_my_info

response:
fatal: remote origin already exists.

me:
git push origin master

response:
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git pushing to a private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842120/git-pushing-to-a-private-repo)

Comment: Nope, its not.. I tried that.. I'll update the original

Comment: Did you try to clone the repo again?

Comment: But I'm ahead of the repo now.. I don't want my changes overwritten

Comment: Things to try:

 1. Clone the repo into a new directory. Success or failure will provide another data point.
 2. Verify that the user you are authenticating with is the same as the user that owns the private repo and that the appropriate [permissions](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization/) are set. `ssh -T git@github.com`

Answer (score 0):

If the URL of the private reo has changed, the proper way to update the remote origin would be:

```
git remote set-url origin https://new/url
```

Then you can try and push again