# Cloning and Pushing a Branch into a Private repo

Tags: git, github

I was given access to a private repo shared for 5 people. 
I did a

```
git clone https://github.com/thecompany/theprogram.git
```

Then I made a new branch and tried to push it using the following:

```
git push --set-upstream the-new-branch
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/thecompany/theprogram.git/' not found
```

How can I push my branch onto github?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842120/git-pushing-to-a-private-repo

Comment: @lost9123193 Where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

> Expectation is to be able to push to a private repo that I am able to clone, but unable to push a branch too.

It depends on what "unable to push a branch to" means.

If it is "repository not found" as in the original question, that means the credentials (potentially cached) used to authenticate when pushing are incorrect.
Test first if a `git ls-remote https://<you>@github.com/<user-or-org>/<private-repo>` works.

If it is a "permission denied" issue, the [permission level](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization#repository-access-for-each-permission-level) might not be high enough (Ie: "read" or "triage" would allow a clone, not a push)

The OP confirms in the comments: he had only read access.

Comment: Yes by unable to push a branch I was referring to the original question. I have tried cleared credentials from osxkeychain. Doing ls-remote I get the list of remote branches with and without the repository listed directly as you suggested. I'm leaning toward a permission denied issue, but would that come back with `remote: Repository not found.`

Comment: @GarrettBarlocker are you using an HTTPS URL or an SSH one starting with `git@github.com:...`?

Comment: And yes, "not found" is a classic answer when you don't have enough rights: a security measure, in order to not reveal the remote repository you are trying to access to.

Comment: I am using a HTTPS URL

Comment: @GarrettBarlocker OK, so if you can clone, it is not a credential issue. Remains the permission level: how were you added to that private repository? With which rights?

Comment: Thanks @VonC it was a permissions issue I only had read-only

Answer (score 1):

when you clone successfully, try this

first, checkout a new branch:

```
git checkout -b  the-new-branch
```

then, push to remote origin(default):

```
git push origin the-new-branch
```

and, set upstream:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/the-new-branch
```