# I created a private repo but I can't push to it from the terminal

Tags: git, github

I created a project in my terminal, Ubuntu. I then did

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "fc"
```

Then, I created a PRIVATE repo on github.

Finally,

```
~$ git remote add github.com/my-user-name/XXXXXXX.git
~$ git push -u origin master
```

But I get this error

```
fatal: 'github.com/my-user-name/XXXXXXX.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have SSH set up with this computer.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842120/git-pushing-to-a-private-repo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git pushing to a private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842120/git-pushing-to-a-private-repo)

Comment: See Github's docs: [Which remote URL should I use?](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/which-remote-url-should-i-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the protocol, like `https://` or `git://`. Without the protocol, the URL refers to a file *on your computer*, which probably doesn't exist.

So for example,

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/my-user-name/XXXXXXX.git
```

Comment: Thank you. I was using the wrong URL. Not the special SSH one.